# Wordpress theme / plugin option page

Tags: wordpress

Is there any substantial difference between the Pluign options or Theme options for admin ?

I can find a lot of good theme related tutorials (for options pages) - but not so much (or not so clear) plugins option page .

Does following the themes related tutorials will be substantial the same ? 
(considering only activation / deactivation hooks would be different ?  )

Edit I - just to clarify:

my question was more specifically, whether I could follow the "themes" tutorials for the settings, even if I need it for "plugins" - and if so, what exactly are the points which I would need to change / pay attention to ..

Comment: learn more at : wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Shivan Raptor - Not so helpful :-) - You could also sent me to the wordpress codex .. If I came here instead of wordpress.stackexchange - I guess i would have my reasons for doing so . If every question about PHP would be answered by a link to the PHP documentation, and every .net question will be sent to the Microsoft website - this site would somehow lose it´s meaning , don´t you think ??

Comment: Agreed. `Plugins options` is for plugins, `Theme options` is for themes. They will appear in different sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weekend I wrote my first plugin after being a WP theme developer since 2007 and I was confronted with the same problems as you.
It turns out that the theme page basically just a simplified version of what you would do to create a plugin page. This often means that functions take lesser arguments and you have less to think about. But it's a double-edged sword since it gives you less freedom about what you wanna do.

E.g: Instead of `add_theme_page()` you would call `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()` depending on where you want your menu to appear. Comparing the arguments:

```
add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
```

Same goes for `add_options_page()` wich is a wrapper function `add_submenu_page()`.

The second thing I noticed is the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). As long as you follow the Codex you and your plugin are save since it takes away all of the actual settings form layout creation. This is what many tutorials out there spend their most energy in: creating hundreds of lines of code to layout forms. Settings API is kind of like a framework for that.

I checked all top google tutorial results for "wordpress theme options page" and only two of them used the Settings API ([this](http://www.onedesigns.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-options-page) and [that](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/) one). So I recommend you do not follow most of the tutorials unless they use the Settings API.

That's it really. Creating a plugin settings in WordPress is nothing more than registering the menu item and rendering the settings via Settings API.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress the way the options are handled are quite similar for both themes and Plugins.

Also if you choose to put a particular option inside theme, then it will be active only as long as that particular theme is activated, the same applies for the Plugin as well.

If you want the functionality to be available only when the theme is activated, then you might have to place them inside theme and if you want it to be active across multiple themes, then you might want to put them inside a Plugin.

The other difference is that, themes might have some special hooks which may not be available for the Plugin.

Also the option/setting page for themes and Plugins are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , my question was more specifically, whether I could follow the "themes" tutorials for the settings, even if I need it for "plugins" - and if so, what exactly are the points which I would need to change / pay attention to ..

Answer (score 0):

This is depending on how a theme or plugin develop. Options are usually stored on the wp_options database. Both of them can benefit from it and substantially the same. But on other case, like a very large plugin, a developer would likely choose to create a TABLE and store the options there.

Comment: Good to hear. If this is the right answer could you add points for Karma. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I do not have a problem to accept and vote, but i do not really understand how your answer is related to the question..I know the settings_api, my question was what are the exact point that are different on the usage for theme and plugins (specific hooks, actions, etc..)